# How Can I perform transaction as well as not locking the table for others to perform changes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, database-design

I am making Web App and i want a table such as Marks_Table to be available all the time so that even if one teacher is uploading marks, students should not be blocked to see their marks from this table.

Comment: The queries that reference the table can use the `with (NOLOCK)` query hint (although that could cause other issues with inconsistent data).  If you are only updating a single row, then the overhead is probably minor.

Comment: Add `WITH(NOLOCK)` to the read queries?

Comment: i am adding multiple rows

Comment: how is this possible with c#

Comment: So let me get this straight. You want to allow a student to view their marks even if the teacher is currently submitting corrected values? This means you intentionally want to provide potentially invalid or incorrect results. Does that really seem like a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example student A has value 5 as grade in the table
Now when student A performs a query he will see grade 5

Now when the teacher is busy with transactions on this table the student gets no results from his query until the teacher is done because his transactions are locking the table.

What you want is that the student does gets resuls from his query while the teacher is doing transactions, he will just see a value 5 because that was the last commited value for him in this table, right ?
In other words, the students can hit F5 and will see their old values until the teacher commits new values, which sounds like a normal way of doing things.

If so you can try this : (only needs to be done once in your database)

```
ALTER DATABASE yourdatabase SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
```

see this : https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/

But also keep in mind that all transactions on tables in your database should be kept as short as possible which would actually avoid the problem in the first place. No student will complain if he has to wait half a second for his results to show after refreshing, they will complain if they have to wait minutes.

Comment: I am using TransactionScope Object to complete and perform transaction, would that solve my problem automatically??

Comment: I am not familiar with the TransactionScope object but since this alter statement is changing the way your database reads records I think it will